# SQL criteria code for listbox to give multi selected results without using VBA?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

So I have a big linked table with historical data that I want to use. I have a state to state lane ID (ex: Alabama to Arkansas) and each lane ID has a column for a low, avg, and high gas price. Over time as I pulled data, these prices for the lane ID's reflect a certain quarter of the year. So say in the second quarter of 2018, the low, avg, and high gas prices from Alabama to Arkansas was $1.25, $1.60, and $2.00. I have over 100,000 lanes of historical data that I want to filter out in a query by its quarter of the year using a multiselect listbox so that the user can filter out a single quarter or multiple quarters and also give the avg of the lane ID because there is more than one record of data for the same lane ID. But I want to build this multiselect listbox using only SQL as I am not too experienced with VBA.

I've built a combobox already that will give me the correct results, but I am only able to select one quarter at a time. After doing research I've found that a listbox allows me to select multiple quarters at one time but the criteria syntax doesn't reflect that of a listbox. I want to build the correct syntax using only SQL in MS Access.

So here is my SQL code so far:

```
SELECT REEFER.[DAT REEFER LANE ID], Avg(REEFER.[PC-Miler Practical Mileage]) AS [AvgOfPC-Miler Practical Mileage], Avg(REEFER.[Spot Avg Linehaul Rate]) AS [AvgOfSpot Avg Linehaul Rate], Avg(REEFER.[Spot Low Linehaul Rate]) AS [AvgOfSpot Low Linehaul Rate], Avg(REEFER.[Spot High Linehaul Rate]) AS [AvgOfSpot High Linehaul Rate]

FROM REEFER
WHERE (((REEFER.[QUARTER OF YEAR])=IIf([Forms]![Form1]![Combo3]="All",[QUARTER OF YEAR],[Forms]![Form1]![Combo3])))

GROUP BY REEFER.[DAT REEFER LANE ID];
```

So really I just want to know if I can build this listbox that allows me to select multiple quarters at once to reflect the correct results in my query using only SQL language.

Comment: Would you happen to know any VBA reference code?

Comment: Have to use VBA to build criteria. Then apply to report. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html. Otherwise, more VBA to modify query using QueryDefs.